# Switching database backend in Mezzanine

Tags: python, mysql, django, mezzanine

I am trying to script a series of examples where the reader incrementally builds a web application. The first stage takes place with Mezzanine's default configuration, using built-in SQLlite:

```
sudo pip install mezzanine
sudo -u mezzanine python manage.py createdb
```

After the initial examples are complete, I want to switch the existing setup to a mysql backend. If that is too complex, I at least want to re-create the built-in examples that come with Mezzanine on the new backend, but Mezzanine won't allow re-running `createdb`

```
CommandError: Database already created, you probably want the migrate command
```

This seems like something that should be incredibly simple, yet I can't seem to get it quite right (and `migrate` alone does not do the trick). Google and official docs not helping either.

Steps I am taking: first, I create a MySQL database on Amazon RDS. Then, I set appropriate configuration for it in myapp/local_settings (I am sure these steps are correct). Then:

```
sudo apt install python-mysqldb
sudo -u mezzanine python /srv/mezzanine/manage.py migrate
```

but then:

```
Running migrations:
   No migrations to apply.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mezzanine project is based on Django, the Python framework.
Unless you encounter a Mezzanine specific problem, most issues can be solved by figuring out how its done the Django way.

*Migrations* is just Django's way of refering to alterations & amendments *within* the DB, ie, the schema (because apps evolve & databases are metamorphic).

In order to actually migrate the data however you could:

1. **Export the contents from the current database, eg:**

   ./manage.py dumpdata > db-dump-in-json.json
   ./manage.py --format=xml > db-dump-in-xml.xml

This may crash if there is too much data or not enough memory. Then the thing would be to use native DB tools to get the *dump*.

2. **Create and add the settings for the new DB in `settings.py`:**
3. **Create the tables and set them up (based on your *models*) on the newly defined DB:**

   ./manage.py makemigrations
   ./manage.py migrate

`createdb` = `syncdb` (create) + `migrate` (set) combined

4. **And reload the exported data there:**

   ./manage.py loaddata db-dump-in-json.json

Comment: syncdb does not appear to be there anymore in Django 1.10 and Mezzanine 4... is it migrate --run-syncdb now?

Comment: looks like it is just too many steps to migrate the data in a tutorial -- probably the right solution is figuring out how to convince mezzanine to set up its default examples again in the new DB (createdb), ideally without uninstalling it...